# hudson latest builds being pushed to updatesite

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugins

I was wondering if there was a plugin or best practice for pushing the latest successful build of a hudson job. To a developer update site.

This is particularly useful for the manual testers as well as getting to them the most up to date version of the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. There are several plugins. To push build artifacts to update sites. That could range from a simple copy to sftp or to deploying your app to an application server. Almost everything is possible.

In addition there is the promotion plugin, that you can use for automatically or manually promoting builds. You can add actions to promotions like sending out an email or running another job or ...

If you want specific answers, post some more information on your system. 
Example questions to answer:
  * What options do you have to push something to your update site?
  * What language is you app written in (e.g. java, php)? What tool do you use for building (e.g. ant, maven)?
  * What does your update site consists of (e.g. WebDAV, Website hosted by apache)
  * Does hudson and the update site run on the same box?
  * .....

Comment: thanks peter! My application is written in java, they are mostly eclipse plugins. We use maven for building. Hudson and the update site are not on the same machine. website hosted by apache. I have a folder that is linked to the website with a url. I need to copy those build artifacts every successful build to developers, and manually upgrade to another update site for customer release, when its ready. 

I really appreciate your help peter.

Comment: For the manual part, If you can script the whole deployment, than you can use the batch or promotion plugin, another job that deploys artifacts from your building job will work too. So you only trigger the manual part when YOU decide it is time.

Comment: For the automatic deployment: Do you copy the successful artifacts to the developers desktop or to a dev/test environment? If it's the latter, than you only need an deployment script, that you call as the last build step (it only executes when the build steps were successful). Check the deployment plugins, if they fit your needs. If you need to deploy to desktops, provide a parametrized job, that the developers start after they got the build successful mail (email extension plugin). They provide their system name and the deployment runs automatically (if you created the job in the right way).